# The data connection could not be established: EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host : Issue only with ftpes

Tags: centos, ftp

I am getting following error while connecting to my ftp server. I have configured my ftp client with following details.

```
ftp host : ftpes://hostname
ftp user : username
password : ********
Port : 21
```

Error message that I am getting.

"Connection attempt failed with "EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host"

but if I change the configuration from ftpes to sftp ( ftp host : sftp://hostname )  it works fine. Can somebody help me on this?

server : cPanel 54.0

Answer (score 0):

ftps/ftpes and sftp are two completely different technologies, served by two completely different daemons. You should be using sftp exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Many cPanel hosts have firewall software blocking ftp port 21. Check with your hosting provider that this is the case. If it's not they should be able to address your specific situation.

EHOSTUNREACH means that the connection could not be established at the IP/port combo requested; usually because it is blocked by firewall. This thread discusses the same situation with another port: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981068/why-is-connect-returning-ehostunreach-when-ssh-works-fine

That being said, sftp on port 22 is secure and transfers files just fine so stick with that.

Comment: Hi Joe, I am the sys admin, I have already confirmed the port 21 is opened. Also if I connect ftp as plain text then it will work fine. The issue only came if I use host as ftpes://

Comment: So no one can connect to this server using ftps on port 21? Is the SSL certificate configured for ftp? Directions here: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Manage+Service+SSL+Certificates

Comment: I can connect it with SFTP, so I believe SSL is installed and working fine. Yes nobody can't connect to the server using ftpes.

Comment: SFTP and FTPS are totally different, so SFTP working has no bearing on FTPS functionality. SFTP is connecting on port 22 using SSH. FTPS is an FTP connection on port 21 with a certificate configured. Please verify in WHM that the certificate is configured for FTP server